# Are yum updates seamless?

Tags: centos, yum

Let's say I want to use yum to update mysql.

Let's also say that I have a cron job that runs some commands using mysql.

If I do a yum update, and then that cron job runs during the update, is there any danger that some of those commands won't run because mysql is being updated?

When mysql gets updated, is there a period of time, like say a split second in-between, where there is no mysql program on disk because the old version got erased before the new version gets copied to disk? Or does that not matter because the computer keeps a copy in memory before erasing it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that cron won't run something that will interfere with or cause problems during the upgrade then temporarily stop the cron daemon before the upgrade and start it again afterwards.

Exactly how you do this depends on your system.  e.g. on a `sysvinit` system, you'd use `/etc/init.d/cron stop` and `/etc/init.d/cron start`.  If using `systemd`, you'd use `systemctl stop cron.service` and `systemctl start cron.service`

Comment: Sounds like your answer is "no."

Comment: At some point during the upgrade process, the old mysql will be stopped.  Some time later (perhaps only milliseconds), the new mysql will be started.  If a mysql-related cron job starts during that time (or during the time it takes for the new mysql to initialise and make itself ready to accept and process requests), it will not run successfully.  BTW, it's not really relevant whether (old or new) mysql is on disk or not - what's important is whether it's running and ready to accept connections and process commands....it can (and, at times, will) be on disk but not running.

Comment: in other words, my answer to the first question is "yes, there is such a danger".

Comment: I meant your answer is "no" to the title question, "Are yum updates seamless?"  But thanks for clarifying regardless.

Comment: i think the question in the title is misguided.  race-conditions and other potential problems are entirely unrelated to `yum` (or rpm...or apt-get or dpkg or whatever) but are inherent to the upgrade process regardless of how it is performed.